# Sinatra helper with setter

Tags: ruby, sinatra

There must be something about helpers in Sinatra I'm not understanding, but wondering why this doesn't work:

```
helpers do
  def session_access_token
   p "GETTING: #{@app_id}_#{@page_id}"
   session["access_token_#{@app_id}_#{@page_id}"]
  end

  def session_access_token=(v)
    p "Setting: #{@app_id}_#{@page_id} access token to: #{v}"
    session["access_token_#{@app_id}_#{@page_id}"] = v
  end
end
```

Then, in an action like this:

```
get '/' do
 session_access_token = 'foo'
 p session_access_token
end
```

I see neither get called (seems like it's creating a new local variable).  That said, when I call 'session_access_token' in other actions, I do see the getter is called.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If, instead of "session_access_token=" I change it to a method named "set_session_access_token" and call it, that works.  Perhaps helpers don't let you define/use methods like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described on the [Sinatra issue](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/433): `something = something_else` never translates into a method call in Ruby. You have to write `self.something = something_else`.